# rebase and push untracked files

Tags: git

I made a git rebase and I fixed merge conflicts:

```
1. git checkout master
2. git pull
3. git checkout loggin-audit
4. git rebase master
```

Now I have

```
  > git branch
* (no branch, rebasing loggin-audit)
  loggin-audit
  master
```

How I can push the committed files into branch loggin-audit?

Answer (score 0):

You are still in the rebase process, to end it repeat this:

```
git commit changed-filesA B C
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Can I do `git commit .`? (to commit all files)

Comment: depends... I usually to `add -u . ; git commit`  or `git add -r foo/; git commit`. to add and commit in a single action you can do `git commit -m "my comment" ./file`, but only if the file is already tracked  (call git add do add or track a file). note that `git add` means "remember the change" so it could also be used to remove a file from the index. therefore, or rather when you realize that add and commit are separate actions, your question becomes less meaningful. There may be some recently implemented shorthand aliases to do what you want, or you can write a shell function.